# Multilevel summarize with dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a set of data like this

```
project,file,line,mutant,killstatus,commitid,isbug
p1,f1,100,NMC,killed,abc123,yes
p1,f1,100,VMC,alive,abc123,yes
p1,f1,200,NVM,alive,ab12de,no
p1,f1,200,NVM,alive,abcde1,yes
p1,f1,200,NVM,alive,abcde2,yes
```

I would like to group by project,file,line and summarize it as

```
project,file,line,total.mutants,killed.mutants,total.commits,bugfix.commits
p1,f1,100,2,1,1,1
p1,f1,200,1,0,3,2
```

That is, for each `project,file,line` combination, the length of `total.mutants` is the unique count of `(mutant,killstatus)`, and `killed.mutants` is the count of `killed` in the previous pair. similarly, `total.commits` is the unique count of `(commitid,isbug)` and `bugfix.commits` is the count of `yes` in the previous pair.

To clarify: 
For `p1,f1,100` there are two unique mutant,killstatus pairs `(NMC,killed),(VMC,alive)` of which one is killed. Hence `2,1` for total, killed
For `p1,f1,200` there is only one unique mutant,killstatus pair `(NVM,alive)` which is alive. Hence `1,0` for total,killed

For `p1,f1,100` there is one unique commitid,isbug pair `(abc123,yes)` which is a bug. Hence `1,1` for total,bugfix
For `p1,f1,200` there are three unique commitid,isbug pairs `(ab12de,no),(abcde1,yes),(abcde2,yes)` of which two are bugs. Hence `3,2` for total,bugfix

Can I use dplyr to summarize it in one go? I managed to do the first partially like

```
data %>% group_by(project,file,line) %>% summarize(
   total.mutants = length(killstatus),
   killed.mutants = sum(ifelse(killstatus == 'alive', F, T))
)
```

but I don't know how to do the unique part, and second part.

Comment: there should be 1 bugfix commit, out of 1 total commit in the first line (100), and 2 bugfix commits out of 3 total commits for the second line (200)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>%
 group_by(project,file,line) %>% 
  transmute(temp1 = paste(mutant, killstatus),

          total.mutants= uniqueN(temp1),
          killed.mutants= uniqueN(paste(mutant[killstatus=='killed'],
                            killstatus[killstatus=='killed'])),
         temp2=paste(commitid, isbug), 
         total.commits= uniqueN(temp2), 
         bug.commits= uniqueN(paste(commitid[isbug=="yes"], 
                            isbug[isbug=="yes"])) ) %>%
         distinct(., project, file, line) %>%
         select(-temp1, -temp2) 
#     project  file  line total.mutants killed.mutants total.commits bug.commits
#    (chr) (chr) (int)         (int)          (int)         (int)       (int)
#1      p1    f1   100             2              1             1           1
#2      p1    f1   200             1              0             3           2
```

---

Or a slightly more compact version with `unite` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
    unite(temp1,mutant, killstatus) %>%
    unite(temp2, commitid, isbug) %>%
    group_by(project, file, line) %>% 
    summarise(total.mutants= n_distinct(temp1), 
               killed.mutants= uniqueN(temp1[grepl("killed", temp1)]),
               total.commits= n_distinct(temp2),
               bug.commits= uniqueN(temp2[grepl("yes", temp2)]))
#     project  file  line total.mutants killed.mutants total.commits bug.commits
#     (chr) (chr) (int)         (int)          (int)         (int)       (int)
#1      p1    f1   100             2              1             1           1
#2      p1    f1   200             1              0             3           2
```

Comment: the `killed.mutants` should be out of `total.mutants` and `bugfix.commits` should be out of `total.commits` (i.e, they are searched within the unique pairs)

Comment: I have clarified in the question. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Say I add `p1,f1,100,NMC,killed,bbb123,yes`  and extra line for `p1:f1:100`, I have 2 mutants in total for that line (which is correct from applying your code), but I will still have only 1 mutant killed, which shows as `2` from your code.

Comment: @rahul Can you try the second piece of code.  I think in the first code block, we have to use the same logic as in `isbug=='yes'`

Comment: @rahul THe other option should also work.  We need to create two `temp` columns.

Comment: @rahul Corrected the first option.